# Importing Spring Project into another Spring Project

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to import a Spring project (project A) into another project (project B) and use the public classes defined in project A.

For a simplified example, I created a public class `DemoClass` in project A:

```
package com.demo.practice

public class DemoClass {
    public String name;
    public DemoClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to use it in project B as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerApplication {

        DemoClass classItem = new DemoClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here are the steps I performed:

1. Run `mvn install` in project A
2. Add a dependency in project B's pom.xml
3. Reload maven project in project B, using the refresh icon on Maven's GUI in Intellij
4. When I try to use it in project B, IntelliJ says `cannot resolve symbol DemoClass` and I am unable to import it as well.

**Project A's codebase**

`DemoApplication.java`

```
package com.demo.practice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`DemoClass.java`

```
package com.demo.practice;

public class DemoClass {
    public String name;
    public DemoClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In Project B, I imported it as follows:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: From your description, you have the correct configuration in pom. Maybe it's an IDE issues (I had this similar issue with IntelliJ many times). I suggest using a terminal, go to your project B and use `mvn compile` to check that your configuration is correct. Terminal shouldn't fail. And if it does, then there's something else you're missing.

Comment: On terminal, it does not compile as well with the error `package com.demo.practice does not exist`.I am importing `DemoClass` as `import com.demo.practice.DemoClass` and using it as `DemoClass classItem = new DemoClass();`

Comment: Go to project A using the terminal and run  `mvn clean install`. Make sure it works without issues. If there's any issue, it won't be installed and you won't be able to reference it in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Right click Project B -> Maven -> Update
2. Run mvn install on project B - This will build your

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do to narrow down what's causing the issue is check your local Maven repo ('{PATH}/.m2/repository/com/demo/practice') and see if the jar for project A is there after running 'mvn install'